# sol[i] = solussaum(x[i]) 'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: google-colaboratory

[image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM4Y1.png)

It completely eludes me as to why this is happening this bit of code is not even mine and I saw it being operated perfectly so I'm at a loss and the solutions I saw before here didn't work so might as well open a new thread

Comment: Please read "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)"
"[I downvoted because an image of your code is not helpful],(http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)"
and "[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)"

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, it was a non problem, I had added and deleted another X variable and it overruled the actual x variable a few cells above